# Helm : how do I Install the latest helm chart from repo

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How do I download the latest chart of package which already has different versions to it?

I tried adding the incubator repo using `helm repo add <repo-name> <repo-url>` and then did a `helm repo update`. And when I tried to download/install the latest chart using the below command:

```
helm install helm-name repo/chart-name
```

It throws the error below:

```
Error:
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '37220'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:37220"

[debug] Original chart version: ""
Error: chart "chart-name" matching  not found in repo index. (try 'helm repo update'). No chart version found for chart-name-
```

Any ideas on how to download the latest chart instead of specifying the chart version everytime?
Or
Does this download the latest charts only if the semver is used for versioning of charts?

Comment: use `helm repo list` to  see whether your desired repo existed in local helm.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the chart you want to install doesn't exist in the repository. Try to list all the charts .
Try `helm repo list` to get the list of all existing charts.

I've just tried `helm install incubator/vdfgdfgdfgfdg --dry-run --debug` to simulate the install of some non-existing chart and got the same error:

```
helm install incubator/vdfgdfgdfgfdg --dry-run --debug
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '45830'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:45830"

[debug] Original chart version: ""
Error: chart "vdfgdfgdfgfdg" matching  not found in incubator index. (try 'helm repo update'). no chart name found
```

Comment: Thanks I have the required chart in repo. I probably thing this issue is due to SemVer

Answer (score 0):

According to helm [docs](https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-install) installing latest version is default behaviour, unless you specify exact version you want. As already described above, your issue most likely caused by missing or misspelled chart and not related to versions.

Comment: Thanks I have the required chart in repo. I probably thing this issue is due to SemVer

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that detecting the `latest` chart version requires that your chart has a valid SemVer (see https://docs.helm.sh/chart_best_practices/#versions)

Otherwise the `latest` mechanism won't work.

Check `helm search` to find out whether your desired chart is listed/ available in repo.

Comment: Thanks. I have versions like 18.08.00-62 , 18.08.00-63 Is this valid semVer